# How do I fix these audio issues and restore my audio settings to their default (xubuntu 15.04)?

Tags: sound, xubuntu

My audio with xubuntu works on a fresh install. But I have been trying to get my bluetooth headphones with xubuntu 15.04. I've given up on doing this, but my regular audio has stopped working.

What I have tried are the solutions here:

http://sourcedigit.com/10777-fix-sound-ubuntu-14-04/

The indicator is gone as well. But pulse audio mixer is installed:

[image]

[image]

When I play audio, the blue bar moves, indicating sound out of hdmi display port. But nothing comes out of line out (plugged in).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer
```

Answer (score -1):

I only do ubuntu 14.04. But I have found no audio out problems are about the permissions given to /dev/snd and the files there. On my systems the files have permissions for user root and group audio.

Note no world permissions so a user must belong to group audio to have permission.

```
ls -l /dev/snd to see permissions.

.....@xen2[2145]ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Mar 22 17:42 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Mar 22 17:42 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Mar 22 17:42 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Mar 22 17:42 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Mar 22 17:42 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Mar 22 18:56 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Mar 22 17:42 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 22 17:42 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 22 17:42 timer

If your /dev/snd files have the same permissions 
grep audio /etc/group and see if you are in that group.  

I added my username to group audio with 
sudo usermod -a -G audio "myusername"
do not quote " your user name.

I use fvwm as a window manager and start gnome stuff in an xterm. Or Gnome-Terminial.

my quick test of sound
gnome-control-center sound see if the sound effect output. 
No then do it with sudo gnome-control-center sound and see if sound effects work. 
if it works for sudo or root and not for you then it is permissions.
```

Comment: Please [**do not add youself to the audio group**](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/) it will make things worse.

Comment: takkat, how would adding oneself to group audio make any things worse.   I do not do an out of the box ubuntu install and on all my systems I have had problems with the sound not working.    My solution is the only solution that works for me.    Three computers and one laptop. latest is a skylake I7 processor.

Comment: Here's a more elaborate post on why in a standard setting no user should  be member of `audio`: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup. FYI [David Henningsson](https://launchpad.net/~diwic) is a senior member of the Ubuntu Audio Developer team.

Comment: If ubuntu developers were the best and brightest then the admonition of member of the audio ivory tower should be followed.  but in that then only way of getting audio to work for me the only non root user on my system to use the system was to chmod of all files in /dev/snd to 666  from 660 every time I rebooted or adding myself to audio